# SQL for Complaint Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm brand new to SQLs and need to pull a report to show the number of spam complaints our system has and which Job Ids/email sends they are associated with.

Would the SQL look like this?

```
SELECT ListID, SubscriberKey, EventDate as [COMPLAINTDATE]
FROM _ListSubscribers
```

When I tried to test it, I keep receiving an error that `ListID` and `EventDate` aren't valid.

Comment: In addition, I've tried this formula as well and have received an error SELECT ListID, SubscriberKey, (Unsubscribe_Reason='Spam_Complaint'),
FROM _Subscribers

Answer (score 1):

`EventDate` is not a field on `_ListSubscribers`. See all fields available on the [_ListSubscribers Data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5). You may want to use `CreatedDate` and depending on if you are on the parent BU or child BU, you may want to add `ent.`.

```
SELECT ListID, SubscriberKey, CreatedDate as [COMPLAINTDATE]
FROM ent._ListSubscribers
```

Also if you're looking for complaints, you're in the wrong data view. Use the [_Complaint data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_complaint.htm&type=5).

```
SELECT ListID, SubscriberKey, EventDate as [COMPLAINTDATE]
FROM ent. _Complaint
```